# Family of disjoint sets of sigma algebra is countable

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

Suppose $(X,S,\mu)$ is a measure space such that $\mu(X)<\infty$. Prove that if $\mathcal{A}$ is a set of disjoint sets in $S$ such that $\mu(A)>0$ for every $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then $\mathcal{A}$ is a countable set.

Comment: Hint: Show that for any positive integer $k$, there must be only finitely many sets $A$ in the given family with $\mu(A) > 1/k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $n$ there can be at most $n\mu(X)$ sets $E$  in the family $A$ such that $\mu (E) >\frac 1 n$ ; if there are more of them then the measures of such sets add up to a number exceeding $\mu(X)$ which is a contradiction. Now $\mu (E) >0$ iff $\mu (E) >\frac1  n $ for some $n$. Hence the given family is a countable union of finite sets.